# NEsper Example explanation - StockTicker

Tags: c#, complex-event-processing, esper, nesper

I'm trying to understand the NEsper and it's examples. It seems like that the example - StockTicker is beginner level. Still I have difficulties to understand and implement this example. Can anyone tell me how to implement and test this example step by step? So I can extend it or understand other examples. After reading the documentation https://www.espertech.com/esper/ I can still not understand. Where can I find more informations? Step by step programming guide will be perfect. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance. Narsu. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is just so unspecific. I would recommend simply copying the code from the NEsper example into a new project and getting that to run. If you encounter any issue doing that you could post the compilation error or something else here.